# FusionAuth setting preferred languages using the java client

Tags: java, fusionauth

I'm using the fusionauth java client in my application to integrate with fusionauth.
When user is registering I want to set him the preferredLanguages in order to send him a verification email in the desired language. The User object has the field `preferredLanguages` marked as `final` and there is no possibility to set in the constructors. How can I do that ?

Comment: Using reflection it works, but I dont't think it is the best idea...
`Reflect.on(user).set("preferredLanguages", asList(Locale.ENGLISH));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All FusionAuth domain objects are open (i.e. not immutable). You can use the Builder pattern with the `Buildable` interface in FusionAuth's Java client to set values easily.

Here's how some code might look:

```
User u = new User().with(u -> u.preferredLanguages.add(Locale.English))
                   .with(u -> u.firstName = "Bob")
                   ...
```

Since `preferredLanguages` is a `List<Locale>`, you can also use `addAll` and any other `List` methods.

While this method doesn't ensure that the `User` object is completely filled out immediately after the constructor returns, Java will ensure that the variable `User u` from my example is fully filled out because the `with` methods all need to return before the left-side assignment is made.